# How to send information to arduíno uno through a bluetooth connection between android app and HC-05 module

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am trying to send data via bluetooth to my arduino, but I think that my android app code is not working properly to do it.

I've tested sending the same information by a serial bluetooth terminal app and it works, so the problem is with my android code.

This is my android app code to send information:

```
public void SetAllAngles_click(View view) {
        try {
            EditText angleInput = findViewById(R.id.angleInputTXT);
            String a = angleInput.getText().toString();

            if (bluetoothSocket != null && bluetoothSocket.isConnected()) {
                OutputStream outputStream = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
                if (outputStream != null) {
                    String data = a + "," + a + "," + a + "," + a + "," + a + ",false";
                    outputStream.write(data.getBytes());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data sent successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OutputStream is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Bluetooth connection is not established", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

It always show me the "Data sent successfully" message, but my arduino is not reciving it.

Comment: have you added the permission in manifest file?

Comment: Yes I have the necessary permissions for bluetooth

Comment: What is your Android version? Are you sure that the connection is made successfully? Do you connect to the right device in your app?